# Subtracting from total if adjacent cell has content

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm looking to subtract from a total derived from the following:

Count the occurrences of the content in cell E2 `=COUNTIF(B:B, E2)`

I want to subtract 1 from that total IF an adjacent cell contains anything.

FOr example:
B2 has content == E2, and C2 is NOT empty, subtract 1 from total
B3 has content == E2, and C3 is empty
B4 has content == E2, and C4 is NOT empty, subtract 1 from total

The end result would be `=COUNTIF(B:B, E2)-2`.

This seemed kind of ridiculous to explain in text so here is an example worksheet with a column expressing where I would like to see the formula, and a column with the expected output.  Programatically this would be a very simple task, but doing it in a spreadsheet is new to me.  I'm hoping this can be done.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xEEyeJx1atsZiDDwCk57KfnbCcZbIavV-gyVF0xuCA/edit?usp=sharing

Also, column `A` and `B` can vary in length, so I would prefer something that adapts to the length of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete range **D:F**

use in **D2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({B1:B, 
 IF((B1:B<>C1:C)*(A1:A<>"")*(C1:C=""), 1, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1),sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 !='' 
  group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could use sql type queries in sheets.  Could you explain the formula a bit in your answer?

Comment: sure, we use `=ArrayFormula(IF((B1:B<>C1:C)*(A1:A<>"")*(C1:C=""), 1, 0))` to construct the auxilary 2nd column directly in query formula to make advantage of `group by` clausule. think of the multiplication used in `IF` as `AND` so TRUE*TRUE*TRUE=1 (1*1*1=1). and then the outer `QUERY` is used to get rid of inner query labels

Comment: Okay.  What is `Col1` and `Col2`?  Is that the results of the `{B2:B, IF((B2:B<>C2:C)*(A2:A<>"")*(C2:C=""), 1, 0)}` query?

Comment: Col1 refers to left side of curly brackets {B2:B, ...} and Col2 refers to the right side IF function {..., IF()}